# iOS store file in cache directory for set length of time

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

We have a POS apartment leasing iPad app that is used to collect a lot of data about a user and their interests (with their knowledge of course).

We use RestKit to sync CoreData with the server, which is totally sweet.

I'm using text files in the cache directory to store a history of their interactions with a guest card, such that it can be submitted in case of error, or sent to us via email, to recreate any guest card in case of some sort of syncing issue.

Although these should be very small text files, probably around 1-3k, I feel as though I should eventually clear these from the cache directory. (As I type this, maybe its so small I shouldn't worry about it).

I was curious if there was any way to clear files from the cache directory after a set amount of time? Say 90 days or so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word on the street is that if you use the sanctioned NSCachesDirectory location, if the OS needs that space, it'll delete things that are in that directory. I've never actually seen it happen in practice, but I've heard such things (and it stands to reason, otherwise why bother having special, OS-sanctioned location for cache files.)

That said, this task sounds pretty straightforward.  Just fire off a low priority GCD background block to iterate through the files in that directory and delete any whose creation date was > 90 days ago. This is really easy if you only care about how long ago the data was created (as opposed to the last time you *accessed* the data which is harder to ascertain without keeping track yourself.)  NSFileManager is your friend here.  Something like this ought to work:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableArray* urlsToDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSURL* dirUrl in [fm URLsForDirectory: NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask])
    {
        NSDirectoryEnumerator* dirEnum = [fm enumeratorAtURL: dirUrl 
                                  includingPropertiesForKeys: [NSArray arrayWithObject: NSFileModificationDate]  
                                                     options: 0 
                                                errorHandler: ^(NSURL* a, NSError* b){ return (BOOL)YES; }];
        NSURL* url = nil;
        while ((url = [dirEnum nextObject]))
        {
            NSDate* modDate = [[dirEnum fileAttributes] objectForKey: NSFileModificationDate];
            if (modDate && [[NSDate date] compare: [modDate dateByAddingTimeInterval: 60 * 60 * 24 * 90]] == NSOrderedDescending)
            {
                [urlsToDelete addObject: url];
            }
        }                
    }

    for (NSURL* url in urlsToDelete)
    {
        [fm removeItemAtURL: url error: NULL];
    }
});
```

To clarify, if you're looking for some mechanism by which to tell the OS 'delete this if I don't access it for more than 90 days' and have it keep track of this for you, I don't believe such a mechanism exists.

Comment: Familiar with NSFileManager and blocks, but not GCD. Mind adding an example to your answer?

Comment: Added example, and then the GCD wrapper for it.